# C++ simple trick with an array pointer improves performance

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

I have found a strange behavior in my heap sort routine (see below).

```
void hpsort(unsigned long n, double *data)
{
  unsigned long i, ir, j, l;
  double rra;

  if (n < 2) return;
  l = (n - 2) / 2 + 1;
  ir = n - 1;

  for (;;)
    {
      if (l > 0) rra = data[--l];
      else
        {
          rra = data[ir];
          data[ir] = data[0];
          if (--ir == 0) { data[0] = rra; break; }
        }

      i = l;
      j = l + l + 1;
      while (j <= ir)
        {
          if (j < ir && data[j] < data[j+1]) ++j;
          if (rra < data[j])
            {
              data[i] = data[j];
              i = j;
              j += j + 1;
            }
          else break;
        }
      data[i] = rra;
    }

  return;
}
```

If I do a benchmark calling this routine like this

```
double* array = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
... fill in the array ...
hpsort(N, array);
```

it takes X seconds. but if I add just a single line

```
void hpsort(unsigned int n, double *data)
{
   ++data;
```

and do benchmark as

```
double* array = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
... fill in the array ...
hpsort(N, array-1);
```

it takes about 0.96X seconds (i.e. 4% faster). This performance difference is stable from run to run.

It feels like `g++` compiler does bounds checking in the first case, while in the second case I can cheat it somehow. But I never heard that bounds checking is done for C arrays...

Any ideas why I get this strange difference in performance?

p.s. compilation is done with `g++ -O2`. by the way, changing `unsigned long` to `long int` also decreases performance by about 3 to 4%.

p.p.s. the "Defined Behavior" version also shows performance improvement

```
void hpsort(unsigned int n, double *data)
{
   --data;
```

and benchmark as

```
double* array = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
... fill in the array ...
hpsort(N, array+1);
```

p.p.p.s. Performance comparison

```
Size of array   Faster  Slower
        10      1.46    1.60
       100      1.41    1.62
      1000      1.84    1.96
     10000      1.78    1.87
    100000      1.72    1.80
   1000000      1.76    1.83
  10000000      1.98    2.03
```

here is my code for `hpsort.cpp`

```
 void hpsort1(unsigned long n, double *data)
 {
   unsigned long i, ir, j, l;
   double rra;

   if (n < 2) return;
   l = (n - 2) / 2 + 1;
   ir = n - 1;

   for (;;)
     {
       if (l > 0) rra = data[--l];
       else
         {
           rra = data[ir];
           data[ir] = data[0];
           if (--ir == 0)
             {
               data[0] = rra;
               break;
             }
         }

       i = l;
       j = l + l + 1;
       while (j <= ir)
         {
           if (j < ir && data[j] < data[j+1]) ++j;
           if (rra < data[j])
             {
               data[i] = data[j];
               i = j;
               j += j + 1;
             }
           else break;
         }
       data[i] = rra;
     }
   return;
 }

 void hpsort2(unsigned long n, double *data)
 {
   unsigned long i, ir, j, l;
   double rra;

   --data;

   if (n < 2) return;
   l = (n - 2) / 2 + 1;
   ir = n - 1;

   for (;;)
     {
       if (l > 0) rra = data[--l];
       else
         {
           rra = data[ir];
           data[ir] = data[0];
           if (--ir == 0)
             {
               data[0] = rra;
               break;
             }
         }

       i = l;
       j = l + l + 1;
       while (j <= ir)
         {
           if (j < ir && data[j] < data[j+1]) ++j;
           if (rra < data[j])
             {
               data[i] = data[j];
               i = j;
               j += j + 1;
             }
           else break;
         }
       data[i] = rra;
     }
   return;
 }
```

and here is my benchmarking code `heapsort-benchmark.cpp`

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <alloca.h>
 #include <limits.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <math.h>

 using namespace std;

 void hpsort1(unsigned long n, double *data);
 void hpsort2(unsigned long n, double *data);

 typedef double element_t;
 typedef void(*Test)(element_t*, element_t*, int);

 const int sizes [] = {10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000};
 const int largest_size = sizes[sizeof(sizes)/sizeof(int)-1];

 vector<double> result_times; // results are pushed into this vector

 clock_t start_time;

 void do_row(int size) // print results for given size of processed array
 {
   printf("%10d  \t", size);
   for (int i=0; i<result_times.size(); ++i) printf("%.2f\t", result_times[i]);
   printf("\n");
   result_times.clear();
 }

 inline void start_timer() { start_time = clock(); }

 inline double timer()
 {
   clock_t end_time = clock();
   return (end_time - start_time)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
 }

 void run(Test f, element_t* first, element_t* last, int number_of_times)
 {
   start_timer();
   while (number_of_times-- > 0) f(first,last,number_of_times);
   result_times.push_back(timer());
 }

 void random_shuffle(double *first, double *last)
 {
   size_t i, j, n;
   double tmp;
   n = last-first;

   srand((unsigned int)0);

   for (i=n-1; i>0; --i)
     {
       j = rand() % (i+1);
       tmp = first[i];
       first[i] = first[j];
       first[j] = tmp;
     }
   return;
 }

 void hpsort1_test(element_t* first, element_t* last, int number_of_times)
 {
   size_t num_elements = (last-first);
   element_t* array = (element_t*)malloc(sizeof(element_t)*num_elements);
   memcpy(array, first, sizeof(element_t)*num_elements);
   hpsort1(num_elements, array);
   free(array);
 }

 void hpsort2_test(element_t* first, element_t* last, int number_of_times)
 {
   size_t num_elements = (last-first);
   element_t* array = (element_t*)malloc(sizeof(element_t)*num_elements);
   memcpy(array, first, sizeof(element_t)*num_elements);
   hpsort2(num_elements, array+1);
   free(array);
 }

 void initialize(element_t* first, element_t* last)
 {
   element_t x = 0.;
   while (first != last) { *first++ = x; x += 1.; }
 }

 double logtwo(double x) { return log(x)/log((double) 2.0); }

 int number_of_tests(int size)
 {
   double n = (double)size;
   double largest_n = (double)largest_size;
   return int(floor((largest_n * logtwo(largest_n)) / (n * logtwo(n))));
 }

 void run_tests(int size)
 {
   const int n = number_of_tests(size);

   element_t *buffer = (element_t *)malloc(size * sizeof(element_t));
   element_t* buffer_end = &buffer[size];

   initialize(buffer, buffer + size); // fill in the elements

   for (int i = 0; i < size/2; ++i) buffer[size/2 + i] = buffer[i]; // fill in the second half with values of the first half
   //random_shuffle(buffer, buffer_end); // shuffle if you do not want an ordered array

   run(hpsort2_test, buffer, buffer_end, n);
   run(hpsort1_test, buffer, buffer_end, n);

   do_row(size);

   free(buffer);
 }


 int main()
 {
   const int n = sizeof(sizes)/sizeof(int);
   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) run_tests(sizes[i]);
 }
```

I compile and run it as

```
g++ -O2 -c heapsort-benchmark.cpp
g++ -O2 -c hpsort.cpp
g++ -O2 -o heapsort-benchmark heapsort-benchmark.o hpsort.o 
./heapsort-benchmark
```

The first column will be faster version

Comment: In second case, shouldn't you allocate one more number?

Comment: @purplepsycho No, since I call it as `hpsort(N, array-1)`

Comment: You say `g++` which implies C++, but you tagged this as C. Which is it? (In C++, your `array-1` adjustment is undefined, and comparing anything to an invalid program isn't very useful. I'm not sure what C thinks about it.)

Comment: Note that `array-1` is UB.  Suggest trying making the allocation 1 `double` bigger, doing  `array+1` and `--data;`

Comment: @molbdnilo as you can see, the code of the heap-sort is pure C. I compile it with g++ since for storing benchmark results I use some STL routines.

Comment: And unless you intialise the values of `array`, reading those is also undefined.

Comment: @JohnSmith That's not how it works. C and C++ are different languages, with different semantics and different restrictions. If you compile with g++, it's C++.

Comment: could it be that if you reference the variable "data" earlier the compiler puts it in a register rather than memory on  the heap?

Comment: As others have said, the behaviour is undefined.   This means the compiler is free to not do checks that would otherwise be required, and is not even required to produce the same result.   It is also quite possible that some code you haven't shown is causing the performance difference (say, related to capturing benchmark metrics).  I am assuming you are initialising array before trying to sort it - failure to do that will also result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembly code for each?

Comment: C and C++ have different rules on how to interpret source code.  So even if the source code is valid for C and another language, the resulting functionality may differ.  Best to tag this post as the language of the compiler.

Comment: "why I get this strange difference in performance?" --> Lack of code showing how your benchmark is derived does not allow for assessing that.  AFAIK, the first code run is always slower than the 2nd (maybe due to caching issues).

Comment: @chux using your suggestion also increases the performance.

Comment: to All: of course I do initialization of the array. I just did not want to put a lot of code here and tried to show only essential parts. if you want, you can do benchmarking in a way, which you think is correct and see that there is a performance change.

Comment: If you compile that code with a C++ compiler, it **is** C++. Identical syntax/grammer does not imply identical semantics. C and C++ are different languages!

Comment: And this is not a code-review site.

Comment: @Olaf And this is not a code-review question. I see an unclear difference in performance of two very similar versions. I do not ask to check my code, since it works fine (sorting is done correctly). I see a lot of questions where people put pieces of code just to explain their question and have never heard that this was a problem.

Comment: How are you measuring the performance?  How big of an array are you sorting?

Comment: Are you always comparing performance of the 2 codes in the same order?

Comment: @chux the performance of two versions is measured inside a single program. I have changed the order of calls several times. The version with ++ and -- always wins no matter what the order is.

Comment: @JohnBode I do several runs for arrays with sizes 10, 100, and so on up to 10000000. For each size N I repeat the calculation 10000000 * log2(10000000) / (N log2(N)) so that different sizes produse comparable times. But anyway, I compare the results only for the same sizes

Comment: @JohnSmith: How are you measuring the performance?  What tools are you using?  gprof?  `clock()`?

Comment: Do you get equivalent performance if you test against 2 copies of the same code?

Comment: Need to see your test code.

Comment: I observe no such consistent difference. Inspection of the assembly code reveals that the main loop of hpsort is compiled nearly identically in both cases (with gcc and clang). There is no evidence of any bounds checking or anything like that.

Comment: `run(hpsort2_test, buffer, buffer_end, n); run(hpsort1_test, buffer, buffer_end, n);` Appears to sort  the list with the first `run()` and then attempt to do so again, except starting with a sorted list?  Is that correct?  It does not appear to be a fair performance comparison.

Comment: @chux yes, the memory for sorting is allocated inside each routine. buffer is used only as storage to copy from.

Comment: Hmmm, Does `run(hpsort1_test, buffer, buffer_end, n);
   run(hpsort1_test, buffer, buffer_end, n);`  (same test done twice) provide consistent results?

Comment: Certainly `start_timer();/timer()` should be around `hpsort1()/hpsort2()` rather than including pre- and post-test code.  All that `malloc()/memcpy()/free()` should not be included in the timing assessment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to get consistent results like OP.

IMO OP's small differences are not part of the difference in code, but part an artifact of testing.

```
void hpsort(unsigned long n, double *data) {
  unsigned long i, ir, j, l;
  double rra;
  ...
}

void hpsort1(unsigned long n, double *data) {
  --data;
  unsigned long i, ir, j, l;
  double rra;
  ...
}
```

Test code

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test(const char *s, int code, size_t n) {
  srand(0);
  double* array = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * n * 2);
  // make 2 copies of same random data
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array[i] = rand();
    array[i+n] = array[i];
  }

  double dt0;
  double dt1;
  clock_t c0 = clock();
  clock_t c1,c2;
  if (code) {
    hpsort1(n, array + 1);
    c1 = clock();
    hpsort(n, &array[n]);
    c2 = clock();
    dt0 = (double) (c2 - c1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    dt1 = (double) (c1 - c0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  } else {
    hpsort(n, array);
    c1 = clock();
    hpsort1(n, &array[n]+1);
    c2 = clock();
    dt0 = (double) (c1 - c0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    dt1 = (double) (c2 - c1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  }
  free(array);
  const char *cmp = dt0==dt1 ? "==" : (dt0<dt1 ? "<" : ">");
  printf("%s %f %2s %f  Diff:% f%%\n", s, dt0, cmp,  dt1, 100*(dt1-dt0)/dt0);
}

int main() {
  //srand((unsigned) time(0));
  size_t n = 3000000;
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    test("heap  first", 0, n);
    test("heap1 first", 1, n);
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}
```

Output

```
heap  first 1.263000  > 1.201000  Diff:-4.908947%
heap1 first 1.295000  < 1.326000  Diff: 2.393822%
heap  first 1.342000  > 1.295000  Diff:-3.502235%
heap1 first 1.279000  < 1.295000  Diff: 1.250977%
heap  first 1.279000 == 1.279000  Diff: 0.000000%
heap1 first 1.280000  > 1.279000  Diff:-0.078125%
heap  first 1.295000  > 1.294000  Diff:-0.077220%
heap1 first 1.280000  > 1.279000  Diff:-0.078125%
heap  first 1.279000 == 1.279000  Diff: 0.000000%
heap1 first 1.295000  > 1.279000  Diff:-1.235521%
heap  first 1.263000  < 1.295000  Diff: 2.533650%
heap1 first 1.280000  > 1.279000  Diff:-0.078125%
heap  first 1.295000  > 1.263000  Diff:-2.471042%
heap1 first 1.295000  < 1.310000  Diff: 1.158301%
heap  first 1.310000  < 1.326000  Diff: 1.221374%
heap1 first 1.326000  < 1.342000  Diff: 1.206637%
heap  first 1.279000 == 1.279000  Diff: 0.000000%
heap1 first 1.264000  < 1.295000  Diff: 2.452532%
heap  first 1.279000  > 1.264000  Diff:-1.172791%
heap1 first 1.279000  > 1.264000  Diff:-1.172791%
```

Comment: @rici OP's code passes `hpsort(..., array - 1)` and then immediately code  increments it `hpsort()` with `++data`.  There is no cache-line alignment difference in `&array[0]` and `&array[n]` unless aliment is wider than 64. (3000000%64 == 0).

Comment: yes, you're right. With large enough arrays, allocating both of them in the same malloc is not different from two separate mallocs.

Comment: @rici But I was _lucky_ with using `n==3000000`.  Had I used `n==3000001`, you point is valid and _may_ apply to OP's sizes.  Hopefully OP will post test code used.